# Can I set the background colour of a Chart.js chart based on the dataset item?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm aware that in [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/), you can pass an array of colours to the `backgroundColor` [option](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#styling), but is it possible to use the current `dataset` item to choose the colour? Ideally, I'd want to do something like:

```js
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "pie",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: scores,
      backgroundColor: (context) => {
         // This is the key bit. Can I somehow access the current
         // dataset item here from the context?
        return context.item.colour
      }
    }]
  }
})
```

Below is a working example where `backgroundColor` is an array but I'd want to change it to use a callback function that sets the background based on the current dataset item:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('chart')

const dataSet = [
  { name: 'John', score: 10, colour: 'orange' },
  { name: 'Bob', score: 5, colour: 'yellow', },
  { name: 'Alice', score: 20, color: 'pink' }
]

const scores = dataSet.map(data => data.score)

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "pie",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: scores,
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'green', 'blue'] // Is there a way I can choose the colour based on the dataset item. Ideally, I'd want to access the array item from dataSet and read the `colour` property from there.
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you want to access the color in the scriptable option you need to pass your dataset as is to chart.js and use the parsing option in the config to tell chart.js in which field in your object the data is it has to show:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('chart')

const dataSet = [{
    name: 'John',
    score: 10,
    colour: 'orange'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    score: 5,
    colour: 'yellow',
  },
  {
    name: 'Alice',
    score: 20,
    colour: 'pink'
  }
]

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "pie",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: dataSet,
      backgroundColor: (c) => c.raw.colour,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    parsing: {
      key: 'score'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map()` to generate an array of colors base on `dataSet`:

```js
backgroundColor: dataSet.map(({ colour }) => colour)
```

---

But you could also use `reduce()` to re-work your `dataSet` variable to the format CharJS expects. Then you don't need the `map()` for the score :

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('chart')

const dataSet = [
  { name: 'John', score: 10, colour: 'orange' },
  { name: 'Bob', score: 5, colour: 'yellow', },
  { name: 'Alice', score: 20, color: 'pink' }
]

const mappedDataSet = dataSet.reduce((p, { score, colour }) => { 
    p.data.push(score);
    p.backgroundColor.push(colour);
    return p;
}, { data: [], backgroundColor: [] });

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "pie",
  data: {
    datasets: [ mappedDataSet ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```